# Finding Correct Nested Class For Input - Java - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The page I am testing has text boxes for data entry, but they are nested within classes of the same name. How would I go about finding the correct one to know which one to enter the data?

Example code:

```
<span class="sectionWrapper"
   <div class="lineItem"
      <div class="Name" title="Fire" </div>
      <div class="itmeLimit"
         <input name="limit">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="lineItem"
      <div class="Name" title="Wind" </div>
      <div class="itmeLimit"
         <input name="limit">
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="lineItem"
      <div class="Name" title="Hail" </div>
      <div class="itmeLimit"
         <input name="limit">
      </div>
   </div>
</span>
```

So basically, I need to enter the values on the input name="limit" field. How would I enter "20,000" for the title Wind?

Here's a snippet of actual code:

```
<span class="sectionWrapper" sort-order="27">
     <div class="linItm_tableTopWrap tableTopWrap_ifSubLine">
     <div class="subLine_tableRowsHeader">
<div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="28">
<div class="linItm_visibleRow visibleRow_ifSubLine">
<a class="linItm_accordionArrow subLine" href="#" style="display: none;"/>
<a class="remove removeLineItem" style="visibility: hidden" name="A. Dwelling - Fire" href="#"/>
<div class="linItm_lineItemName" title="A. Dwelling - Fire">A. Dwelling - Fire</div>
<div class="linItm_date">08/25/2015</div>
<div class="linItm_limit_wrap">
<div class="linItm_limit_dollarInput">
<input class="currencyInput contentRow_amountInput resetPremiums limitInput maxMin" type="text" style="text-align:right" value="0.00" name="limit"/>
<div class="inputDollarSign">$</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="linItm_deductible_wrap">
<div class="linItm_proRataPremium_wrap contentRow_rataPremium black">
<div class="linItm_annualPremium_wrap black">
<input class="linItm_manualCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="manual"/>
<a class="view" href="#" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
<div class="linItm_accordionRow accordionRow_ifSubLine" style="height: 0px;"/>
</div>
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="29">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="30">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="31">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="32">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="33">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="34">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="36">
     <div class="linItm_tableRow subLine_tableRow" sort-order="37">
     <div class="visibleRow_ifSubLine_bottomArea"/>
</span>
```

Comment: You can use a selector to select all divs with class lineItem and then you can iterate through the children of those, looking for an attribute with name "title" and value "Wind". On a succesful match you select the input from that div and enter 20,000. It's all in the Selenium API docs (look for selectors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all divs that can contain the input:

```
List<WebElement> lineItemDivs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".lineItem"));
```

Iterate through the children of each div till an element with the appropriate attribute key/value is found. If such an element is found, find the input field of that specific div and type in the wanted value:

```
for (WebElement div : lineItemDivs)
{
    if (div.findElements(By.cssSelector("[title='Wind']")).size() > 0)
    {
        div.findElement(By.tagName("input")).sendKeys("20000");
    }
}
```

Comment: So after reworking the syntax a little, I get the following error: The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) List<WebElement>, int

Comment: `List<WebElement> lineItemDivs = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".subLine_tableRow"));
    
    for (WebElement div: lineItemDivs) {
     if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[title='A. Dwelling - Fire']")) > 0) {
       driver.findElement(By.tagName("input")).sendKeys((String.valueOf(20000))); continue;
     }
    }`

Comment: The `if` was missing `.size()` when comparing to 0.

Comment: Fixed some other formatting and code issues. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks @JeffC for that! Added the .size() to the if and it fixed that. Now I've got another problem I'm going to have to try and overcome. For whatever reason, it is saying it cannot interact with it because it is hidden. I see where <a class="remove removeLineItem" shows as hidden, so I wonder if it is trying to pick up on that somehow? I'm still playing with it, but I am just having a hard time with this one...

Comment: Selenium, as designed, will not interact with elements (without hacks/workarounds) that the user cannot interact with. Make sure that you  script whatever a user needs to do to make that element visible and able to interact with and the script should work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. You can use an XPath locator and locate the input in one go:

```
//div[contains(@class, "linItm_visibleRow") and div/@title="A. Dwelling - Fire"]//input[@name="limit"]
```

Comment: This does not find any items. I tried implementing additional criteria as well, but no luck.

Comment: @DustinN. then, there is a reason for it. The HTML you presented is not actually well-formed  `<div class="lineItem"` lines don't have a closing `>`. Also, are there any iframes on the page? And, what error are you currently getting?

Comment: That initial HTML was just some pseudo code I threw together to try and give a simplified representation of what I am facing. I messed up some of the syntax for sure. I have since added a snippet of actual code to see if maybe it can lead to a working resolution.

Comment: @DustinN. okay, how about this version (based on your real HTML)?

Comment: I get "The given selector is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement" with the modified version.

Comment: @DustinN. the selector is correct syntactically and it points to an input element. Anyway, it's still guessing, I have no way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am still messing around with it trying to figure out why it's not picking it up.